# how to get two web services data into a table view in swift 3?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

In this table view i had three sections but for third section i am loading the data using second url and passing dynamic height and will set height depending on array count here sometimes i was getting height and sometimes i was getting nill value can anyone help me how to resolve this ?

The code for this is shown below

```
self.shippingmethodURL()
self.shippingaddressURL()

func shippingmethodURL() {
        guard let url = URL(string: self.shippingMethodURl) else {return}
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let data = data, let jsonObj = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)) as? [String:Any] {
                self.arrayss = jsonObj as [String : AnyObject]
                for value in jsonObj.values {
                    if let array = value as? [[String:Any]] {
                        for element in array {
                            if (element["name"] as? String) != nil {
                                self.totalCount += 1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async { 
                    let sectionHeight = self.arrayss.count * 31
                    let cellHeight = self.totalCount * 44
                    self.heightStart = sectionHeight + cellHeight
                }
            }
        }).resume()
    }
    func shippingaddressURL() {
        let url = NSURL(string: self.url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let data = data, let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
            self.shippingArray = (jsonObj!.value(forKey: "address") as? [[String: AnyObject]])!
                let key = "default"
                for obj in self.shippingArray {
                    if let dict = obj[key] {
                        self.defaultArray.append(dict as! Int)
                    }
                }
                if self.defaultArray.contains(1) {
                    self.addressSelected = true
                    self.selected = false
                } else {
                    //item could not be found
                }
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                    self.tableDetails.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }).resume()
    }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if ((addressSelected == true || checkIsPaymentRadioSelect == true) && selected == false){
                if (indexPath.section == 0) {
                    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
                }
                else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
                    return 62
                }
                else {
                    if height == 0 {
                        if heightStart == nil {
                            shippingmethodURL()
                        }
                        return CGFloat(heightStart!)
                    }
                    else{
                        return CGFloat(self.height)
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                if (indexPath.section == 0){
                    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
                }
                else if (indexPath.section == 1){
                    return 62
                }
                else {
                    return 0
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: what you want when web service return no data?

Comment: i need to return the data from shipping method url height value depending on array count @MuhammadZohaibEhsan

Comment: Can you show your response structure?

Comment: for table view height was not passing from web services sometimes it was passing as mentioned in shippingmethod function @iPeter

Comment: `shippingmethodURL `, What is this method returning?

Comment: i am getting the height for my third section @iPeter

Comment: Can you please be more specific, your requirement is still not clear.

Comment: do you see shipping method url function in my code in that i am calculating the no. of arrays count and calculating row height so that i am dynamically passing the height for my third section but here the problem that sometimes it was returning height 282 which i want and sometimes it was returning nil in that value place @iPeter